# Android emulator (sdk 4.1) doesn't scroll wallpaper

Tags: android, android-emulator

The wallpaper in my sdk 4.1 Emulator doesn't scroll (panning). Scrolling occurs as expected with sdk 2.2. Is there an option to make the wallpaper scroll?